# Почему перезаписывается id?

Tags: php

Есть 1й файл в котором передается id через hidden input и есть 2й файл который получает данный id, при выводе id в 1м файле на экран всё правильно работает, но при отправке в другой файл он перезаписывается, почему? Как исправить?

Файл 1:

```
  <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM UserNotes";
            if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
                foreach ($result as $value) {
                    $id = $value['id'];
                    $Title = $value['Title'];
                    $Note = $value['Note'];
                ?>
       // весь блок тоже в цикле
            <button name="button" type="submit" class="plates">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id?>"> 
               <?php print_r($id);?> // Выводится правильный id 
              <input type="hidden" name="Title" value="<?=$Title?>">
              <span class="Notes"><?php echo $Title?></span>
            </button>
  <?php
     }
    }
  ?>
```

Файл 2:

```
      <?php

        if(isset($_POST['button'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];// идет перезапись на последнюю цифру id
         $sql = "SELECT Title,Note FROM UserNotes where id='$id' ";// 
        print_R($id); // Т.к блоков 2 он выводит всегда 2
         if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
          foreach($result as $val){
          $Title = $val['Title'];
          $Note = $val['Note'];
     }
    }
   }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Эти кнопки у вас внутри формы. Когда вы отправляете форму, то вы получаете сразу все кнопки и инпуты. Вы можете проверить это добавив квадратные скобки в имя `name='id[]'`. Так в `$_POST` вы получите массив значений у которых были имена `id`.

Теперь как это исправить? Вы можете в момент отправки формы ловить событие с помощью `js` и на ненужных кнопках и полях ввода ставить атрибут `disabled`, что отключит их для отправки.

Либо, что как мне кажется, проще в вашем случае: берём и оборачиваем не список кнопок формой, а каждую кнопку формой. Их 'action', 'method' не поменяются, однако это поможет вам избежать отправки всех данных сразу.
Примерно так:

```
<?php
foreach($result as $value)
{
    ... ?>
    <form action='...' method='...'>
        <button>
            ...
        </button>
    </form>
<?php ...
} ?>
```